# Using xdebug with a front-end js SPA?

Tags: php, phpstorm, vue.js, xdebug

I have xdebug working great when I access my server directly (thru a vhost entry to the IP set up by homestead/vagrant). However, I have a decoupled frontend that I'm running on localhost:8080, that talks to that laravel backend server, but xdebug doesn't trigger on those requests. I *think* I just have to set the cookie `XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM` in my requests coming from the front-end, however I'm not sure how to do that with vue-resource as I didn't see anything in the docs for this. I tried the following:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Cookie'] = 'XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM'
```

however, I get warned `Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"` by chrome. Anyone have ideas of anything else I can try?

Comment: btw I just tested and I can manually add `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` as a get param and it successfully triggers xdebug, so I'm pretty sure if I can figure out how to add that cookie on every request with vue-resource I should be golden

Comment: **a)** `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini -- will attempt to debug every single request (regardless of cookies or GET/POST parameters) **b)** Place `xdebug_break();` in actual PHP code -- programmatic breakpoint that will also initiate debug session (downside -- need to edit PHP code for that) **P.S.** These are universal solutions that have no relation to the editor used (PhpStorm in our case).

Comment: That works, nice. Kind of annoying to have to add in the `xdebug_break()` but in lieu of something else I'll take it. If you want to repost as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: FWIW I just added a normal breakpoint and no `xdebug_break()` and it still worked, nice!

Comment: If you did A) **and** B) then no wonders -- they are alternative approaches (so should read `a) OR b)`)

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of possible approaches outside of using COOKIE or GET/POST parameter.

1. Use `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini. This option instructs Xdebug to attempt to debug every single request (regardless of cookies or GET/POST parameters).

   Do not forget to restart you web server / PHP so that it will read you new config file.

   Downside: will attempt to debug **every single request**, even if no debugging is required, so you may see approx 1 sec delay while Xdebug is trying to establish a debug connection.
2. Place `xdebug_break();` in the actual PHP code: a programmatic breakpoint that will initiate debug session if not yet established and will stop at that line.

   Downside: need to edit PHP code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating the answer by @LazyOne I'd like to add that for **xDebug v3+** you should use

`xdebug.start_with_request=yes`

instead of

`xdebug.remote_authostart=1`